# Showing Datatables results on Leaflet sidebar

Tags: jquery, css, datatables, leaflet, sidebar

I am using [Leaflet Sidebar](https://github.com/turbo87/leaflet-sidebar/) to create web page. When users click on the pin, I would like the sidebar to show the contents of a dynamic web page generated through Datatables (already functional). I am using jQuery *.load* to show the page (which works) but I get the headers and static text, **not** the results of the table (loaded). Here is the [working example](http://educacaoaberta.org/leaflet/).

It seems like I need the Datatables to be processed first before showing the results inside the *div*, any tips?

```
layer.on("click",function(feature){
sidebar.show();
sidebar.setContent(html);
$("#sidebar").load("dados/DATATABLES.html")
```

Comment: You've got two 404 errors, correct this first! `http://educacaoaberta.org/leaflet/script/jquery.dataTables.min.js?_=1433184656750` `http://educacaoaberta.org/leaflet/script/currency_sort_br.js?_=1433184656751`

Comment: Actually four 404 errors.

Comment: You're right. Fixed.

Comment: `http://educacaoaberta.org/leaflet/index.json` still 404. Is it from this json file your results coming?

Comment: No, the map_oer.json is where the results come from. It should just need the map_oer.html + map_oer.json to show the results.

Comment: You are doing several asynchronous requests and you have to check the dependencies. Like 'wait this finishes then do next request'. Try to organize the order of requests. When I click on pin, 6 requests are firing.

Comment: Makes sense, I'll look into how to do this (a bit of a newbie on this). Any pointers are welcome.

Comment: If you put your code on a JSFiddle, we can help you better.

Comment: I tried, but I don't know how to put the .html that is called by jquery there to work. But I did manage to improve on the code and indeed it is a problem of something like a callback that is needed. Datatables needs to process before the .load(file.html) is called. I tried 
`$.when( $("#sidebar").load(feature.properties.file) ).done(function ()` but this won't work. I also looked at Datatables `init` but haven't gotten that to function.

Comment: The new working site is: http://educacaoaberta.org/leaflet/. I also made it available here https://github.com/tamielbr/datatables-map

Comment: Seems to have been fixed by appending:
`"initComplete": function(settings, json) {}` to the 
`$('#table_data').dataTable( {` call. I'll keep testing.